# Permissions issue with a Docker container running Mongo - Operation not permitted

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to get a Docker Mongo container to run on my local machine through WSL. I am mapping folders in my Windows file system to the container's file system, which is causing permissions issues. The mapped folders are owned by root while the logged in user is `mongodb` (uid:999 gid:999). I have tried numerous ways to change the ownership of these mapped folders to the mongodb user to no avail and am hoping someone would know where the issue lies. This is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
services:
  mongo:
    hostname: mongodb
    image: mongo:5.0.21
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
      - ./mongo/:/etc/mongo/
      - ./mongo/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    command: "--config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf --bind_ip_all"
```

When starting my container without any changes to the original, my container exits immediately after getting this error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/mongo/mongodb.key': Operation not permitted
```

When adding `user: '1000:1000'` to my docker-compose, I get a slightly different error:

```
Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db
```

I've tried removing authentication, adding a chown command in my Dockerfile without any success. I've tried a slew of other things I could find on the internet although I usually kept seeing the same errors I posted above.

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: can you provide the content of your mongod.conf ?